# Algorithm to suggest which chart to build using structure of the data

Tags: algorithm, charts, prediction

I am working on a development where we need to dynamically generate visuals based on data. Structure of data changes based on query fired on data.
I have seen this feature in many BI tools where it suggests the type of suitable visualization based on data structure.
I have tried creating my own algorithm based on rules which we generally use to create a chart.
I want to know if there are any such algorithms or rules which can help us build this

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to give you a head start here with what I could think. Since you have mentioned you have already tried writing your own algorithm with rules, please show your work. As far as I know the chart types can be determined based on the nature of `(x, y)` points you're trying to plot.

- For a single `x`, if there are many corresponding `y` values, go with scatter plot.
- For a single `x`, if there is only one corresponding `y` value,

  - If `x` takes  integer values, go with line charts
  - If `x` takes rather string values, go with bar charts